# FancyRpartPlot - What does the number inside the node mean?

Tags: r

anyone know what does it means? I have a confusion on the information inside the decision tree below. I tried to find the number sources inside the variable. Hence, i could not find anything

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Normally you see the probability of each class and the percentage of cases falling in that class when you plot with fancyRplot- but in your case, your attribute perhaps is a numeric, and then in the box is the mean of responses for that split.

Comment: Hi RomRom, thank you for your information, but how can i determine which value belong to which value at the origin? cause during the prediction, i change into numeric. is it possible to find inside "Train" variable?